# I need to delete a record based on duplicate usernames and different content in another column

Tags: database, duplicates, ms-access-2016

I am using Access 2016.
I have a database that keeps track of all employees and what Safety training they have taken.
I need to figure out a query that looks for duplicate usernames (column is called mis_user) and if it finds a duplicate username, it needs to delete the record that contains Crisis Intervention Medium and High Risk in the column: object.

The table is called: 1-DC-Crisis_eLearn_HRIS_Combined

In the example image attached, AbSmith is in column mis_user twice. Look in the next column (object column) and you can see that AbSmith has taken the Medium and High Risk course, as well as the Re-Certification (All Level) course.  So, for AbSmith, I need to delete the record that contains Crisis Intervention Medium and High Risk. [image showing the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlKPv.png)

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be done?
I appreciate any and all help.
Thank you
Deb :)

Answer (score 0):

First, make a backup of the table.

Next, try this query:

```sql
Delete 
    *
From 
    [1-DC-Crisis_eLearn_HRIS_Combined]
Where 
    [object] = "Crisis Intervention Medium and High Risk Certification"
    And Exists
    (Select T.mis_user 
    From [1-DC-Crisis_eLearn_HRIS_Combined] As T
    Where T.mis_user = [1-DC-Crisis_eLearn_HRIS_Combined].mis_user
    And T.object <> "Crisis Intervention Medium and High Risk Certification")
```

Comment: Gustav - you are my hero! Thank you Thank you! I copied and pasted your data, ran it and it works! You are brilliant! You have saved me so much time and you have made our Safety Training reports 100% accurate! Thank you!

Comment: Oh, love that. Then please mark as answered, if you feel so.

Comment: Gustav, at the weekly huddle meeting this morning, I told everyone about your help. Your name is now posted in big green letters, on the "Weekly Recognition" section of our white board, in a hospital, in St. Thomas, Ontario, Canada and the whole team thanks you!